# Is FTP file sharing faster than cloud storage alternatives e.g dropbox / google drive / mediafire

Tags: ftp

I work doing DCP (digital cinema packages) for trailers, the files are usually a zip of 1-2 gig.

I have been just uploading them to an ftp on a cloud hosting and sending the links with username/password, and that works most of the time but lately there has been some clients that experience time out while downloading and unable to resume (clients being local cinemas downloading the files)

I know some foreign production houses use dropbox and similar web based file sharing to send their big files but I wonder if is there any alternative to FTP and web based file sharing aside from torrents ?

Comment: This question is better suited to SuperUser.

Comment: Thanks I will post there. First time in stackoverflow :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had FTP timeout issues delivering broadcast-sized media, especially with distant clients.  In some cases, I use 7Zip volume split archives to deliver the large file in smaller pieces, which speeds up the overall transfer (multiple downloads at once) while preventing timeouts.  The client needs to be somewhat technically inclined, as it involves using a 7z archiver like 7Zip or PeaZip.  They basically download all the pieces into a single folder, and when they open the first file, it shows the whole file they can then extract (I usually go with 256MB pieces).

Here's a how-to I found real quick, but there are plenty others out there:  http://www.linglom.com/it-support/how-to-split-a-large-file-using-7-zip/